# Fetching all Tags from Instagram Using Python

Tags: python, api, python-2.7, instagram, instagram-api

I've tried different ways to fetch tags from Instagram. I only manage to collect 20 tags at the first place, so I try to do pagination. I tried doing pagination using max_tag_id, it works but I only get 10 tags.

Can anyone help me? How to make use of max_tag_id?

Here's my code:

```
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)
recent_media, next_ = api.tag_recent_media(count=50, max_tag_id = 1025682445569329407, tag_name="Starhub")

count = 0
for media in recent_media:
    print media.caption.text, "--->", media.user.username
    print ""
    count += 1

print count
```